# How to execute command from the controller and pass parameters to it? LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

I have a function of the controller where it calls me a command where I must pass it a list of projects that were assigned to a translation so that it looks for me in another table and registers them as recurrent contacts.

The issue is that I can not execute the command always throws me an error and I made the reference and nothing.

It throws me problems because I want to pass parameters to the command.

**Controller**

```
public function syncTranslate(Request $request,Project $project){
        $this->authorize('update translate', TranslateProject::class);
        
        $translateWithouthProyect = TranslateProject::filterData()->get();
       
        Artisan::call('fidelizaleads:quotesWithoutProjects',$translateWithouthProyect);
        exit;

return redirect()->route('translate.index')->with(notify()->success($count .' traducciones fueron añadidas al proyecto '. $project->name));

    }
```

**Command**

```
protected $signature = 'fidelizaleads:quotesWithoutProjects';

 protected $translate;
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($translate)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->translate = $translate;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Quote::executeQuoteTranslation($this->translate);
        
    }
```

And this is the error message he throws at me

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to guess that you are passing a Collection as the second argument to `call`. You would have to ask that Collection for the underlying array:

```
Artisan::call('fidelizaleads:quotesWithoutProjects', $translateWithouthProyect->toArray());
```

You can use `toArray()` on the Collection to get the array.

Though I am not sure what passing that array is going to do as you don't have any parameters for that command and the array is usually an associative array.

Comment: If it is an object array it is like a SELECT * FROM TRANSLATE WHERE PROJECT_ID IS NULL;

@lagbox

Comment: what type of object is it? as you can't pass an object as the second parameter ... and your command doesn't take parameters

Comment: I don't know how to add parameters to the commands, first time I work with them.?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#defining-input-expectations   check out that part of the docs  or the doc version for what ever version you are using